# how to calculate year and it value?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, pivot

I have got some result for this query but instead of it i want to change a result like below

Result to be shown::

```
    2011                     2012
    26267.620000000003       404603.20999999996
    144384.36                173245.96000000002 
    199704.47999999998       208524.42
```

Query

```
SELECT
    YEAR (PAYMENTDATE) AS YEARNUMBER,
    MONTH (PAYMENTDATE) AS MONNUMBER,
    SUM (AMOUNT) AS MONTOTAL
    FROM 
    PAYMENTS
    GROUP BY 
    YEAR (PAYMENTDATE)
```

Result:: for above query

```
2011        26267.620000000003  
2011        144384.36   
2012        173245.96000000002  
2012        208524.42
```

Comment: k ...then how to change as like above my result

Comment: You need pivot as, for example, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT MONNUMBER, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN YEARNUMBER = 2011 THEN MONTOTAL ELSE 0 END) AS Year2011,
       MAX(CASE WHEN YEARNUMBER = 2012 THEN MONTOTAL ELSE 0 END) AS Year2011
FROM (SELECT YEAR(PAYMENTDATE) AS YEARNUMBER, MONTH(PAYMENTDATE) AS MONNUMBER, 
             SUM(AMOUNT) AS MONTOTAL
      FROM PAYMENTS
      GROUP BY YEAR(PAYMENTDATE)
    ) AS A
GROUP BY MONNUMBER
```

Comment: SQL error #1:Syntax error: Encountered "2011"  it showing some error like this??

Comment: Again same error SQL error #1:Syntax error: Encountered "\'2011\'" at line 2, column 69

Comment: k k i wil try to solve??